# powershell click google sreach result

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

i have a powershell script open google search and find a specific website , click on link and open the web site

```
$i=0    
While ($true) {
    if ($StatusCode = Test-Connection -ComputerName 8.8.8.8 -Quiet) {

$IE = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate(googel search address )
$IE.visible=$true

while ($IE.busy) {sleep  10}
$Link = @($IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "www.iranelectronic.com/"})[0]
if ($Link -eq $null){ $Link = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("cite") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "www.iranelectronic.com/"} }
if ($Link -eq $null){$ie.quit();Break}
$Link.click()
start-sleep 10
$ie.quit()
 Break

     }

      else {
           foreach ($_ in 1..10){
           $i++
           start-sleep 900        
           $StatusCode = Test-Connection -ComputerName 8.8.8.8 -Quiet
           }
           Break  
         }
     }
```

but not working in windows 7 ie version 10 and $link in null !
windows 10 ie version 11  is working great

i check inspect element internet explorer version 10 on windows 7 and get this result :

```
<div class="rc"><div class="r"><a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AOvVaw2SZfaltNouKdqFDN6YQ_p3','','2ahUKEwiJjurWwLrfAhVELFAKHaPRCyMQFjAAegQIABAC','','',event)" href="http://www.iranelectronic.co/"><h3 class="LC20lb">ایران الکترونیک بزرگترین مرکز پخش انواع قطعات ...</h3><br><div class="TbwUpd" style="display: inline-block;"><cite class="iUh30"><span dir="ltr">www.iranelectronic.co/</span></cite></div></a><span><div class="action-menu ab_ctl"><a class="GHDvEf ab_button" id="am-b0" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="گزینه‌های نتیجه" href="#" data-ved="2ahUKEwiJjurWwLrfAhVELFAKHaPRCyMQ7B0wAHoECAAQAw" jsaction="m.tdd;keydown:m.hbke;keypress:m.mskpe"><span class="mn-dwn-arw"></span></a><div tabindex="-1" class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role="menu" data-ved="2ahUKEwiJjurWwLrfAhVELFAKHaPRCyMQqR8wAHoECAAQBA" jsaction="keydown:m.hdke;mouseover:m.hdhne;mouseout:m.hdhue"><ol><li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AOvVaw0bYKQCsuGdo8sgrLerKTQW','','2ahUKEwiJjurWwLrfAhVELFAKHaPRCyMQIDAAegQIABAF','','',event)" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qlEq1WcGd3sJ:www.iranelectronic.co/+&amp;cd=1&amp;hl=fa&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=ir">ذخیره&nbsp;شده</a></li><li class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role="menuitem"><a class="fl" href="/search?q=related:www.iranelectronic.co/+iranelectronic&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiJjurWwLrfAhVELFAKHaPRCyMQHzAAegQIABAG">مشابه</a></li></ol></div></div></span></div><div class="s"><div><span class="st">پست الکترونیک: info@<em>iranelectronic</em>.co تلفن: 07132358510 - 07132338668 - 07132333600 فکس: 07132348649 همراه: 09171166771 آدرس: شیراز، خیابان زند،&nbsp;...</span></div></div></div>
```

help me to resolve this problem
thanks .
Regards

Comment: I am little confused here with the description in original post. You said first you are searching the website using google search. If you already know the URL of the site than why you need to search it using google. You can directly navigate IE to that site address. So if you have any specific purpose of doing that than can you please try to describe it for us? may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but if you are searching for a link, why try and find the `<span>` or `<cite>` element?
I think this should get you the link to perform the click() on:

```
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.href -like 'http://www.iranelectronic.co*'}
```

As a sidenote, I would advise to not just quit IE, but also clear it from memory when done:

```
$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thanks Bro theo , not working !!! , after change Internet Explorer Version tag is change i want if don,t found website link on <span> tag search for <cite> tag to try found website link .

Comment: Well, as far as I know, unless a `<span>` or `<cite>` tag has an `onclick()` function defined, you will not get the browser to perform `$Link.Click()` on that. The `<a>` tag in HTML defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another. The most important attribute of the `<a>` element is the `href` attribute, which indicates the link's destination...